# Is there compulsion of using `FrameLayout` for loading fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have seen that most of the people use `FrameLayout` for loading `Fragments`.
My question is **Why FrameLayout ?** and why not the others like `LinearLayout`,`RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`.Most of the answers on StackOverflow says **FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item.** But the others can also block the whole screen if the its height and width set to `match_parent`.
What is the difference ?
Why most of the people choose `FrameLayout` if others can do the same job ?

Thanks in advance
Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use anything (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`).

`FrameLayout` is just the most basic `ViewGroup` that provides the least functionality. It is ideal to use if you only need to hold a single child - in this case, a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

`FrameLayout`  To load child one above another, like cards inside a frame, we can place one above another or anywhere inside the frame.
Designed to display a stack of child View controls. Multiple view controls can be added to this layout. This can be used to show multiple controls within the same screen space.

`LinearLayout` Designed to display child View controls in a single row or column. This is a very handy layout method for creating forms.

`RelativeLayout` Designed to display child View controls in relation to each other. For instance, you can set a control to be positioned “above” or “below” or “to the left of” or “to the right of” another control, referred to by its unique identifier. You can also align child View controls relative to the parent edges.

For more information, please check this
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#CommonLayouts

I hope it's helpful to you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so much good at programming but I can give you some reasons.

First, have a look at official docs.

> In order to replace one fragment with another, the activity's layout includes an empty FrameLayout that acts as the fragment container. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui#AddAtRuntime

This means for switching between multiple fragments we have to use FrameLayout. Why Framelayout then? Another look at the official docs.

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, **FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other**. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

It can block out an area of the screen to display a single item. Other layouts could do the same thing too. So Frame?

Because FrameLayout has one characteristic that other layouts don't have.

> FrameLayout can hold its child one above another, like a deck of cards. In a deck of cards, one card is placed above other.

FrameLayout does the same job. When you use FrameLayout as a fragment container it holds the child fragment one above other as your code wants. Then it shows one and left others behind it, you switch back to other fragments then it comes above and others go behind again.

That's all I know.